# What's being raised on my wooden raised garden bed?

Tags: diagnosis, pests, raised-beds

This has been on my wooden raised garden bed from long time(now almost 5-6 months) and all over it. Not sure what's it. I haven't seen any insects roaming around, none of my plants have any damage (all plants are healthy).
Not sure if this is a termite infestation. Do I need to worry/treat/remove this raised garden bed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like sap from when the board was freshly cut. Not a problem.